# Images on Active Storage not displayed on the ERB page but another ERB page are displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am bit lost somewhere, as I have build gallery with active storage and it's fine and I am able to see images and upload the images

Here is a screenshot
[image]

But one problem, as I try to create a new page for listing page, I am trying to get images on thumb page

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <ul class="sidebar-list">
      <li class="sidebar-item"><%= link_to "Your tools Listings", tools_path, class: "sidebar-link active" %></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Listings
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <% @tools.each do |tool| %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <%= tool.images %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <h4><%= tool.listing_name %></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 right">
              <%= link_to "Update", listing_tool_path(tool), class: "btn btn-black-free-account" %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr/>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

it should be fine as long it shows a text-based of images see screenshot below

[image]

So I need to change these images as I am using the same method as the first screenshot, as the code below

```
<% if @tool.images.attached? %>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Photo Display
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <% @tool.images.each do |image| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default tools-gallery-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading preview ">
                    <%= link_to image_tag(image, class:"img-thumbnail tools-gallery"), image %>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                       <%= link_to "Remove", delete_image_attachment_tool_path(image), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>

    </div>
```

so I copied

```
 <%= link_to image_tag(image, class:"img-thumbnail tools-gallery"), image %>
```

this to new listing pages stuff

so I modify the listing page

```
<% @tools.each do |tool| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= tool.images %>
          <%= link_to image_tag(tool.images, class:"thumbnail"), images %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <h4><%= tool.listing_name %></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right">
      <%= link_to "Update", listing_tool_path(tool), class: "btn btn-black-free-account" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr/>
<% end %>
```

and all I got an error 
[image]

even I have tried this

```
  <%= link_to image_tag(tool, class:"thumbnail"), images %>
```

Tool.rb

```
class Tool < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_many_attached :images

  validates :tool_type, presence: true
  validates :power_type, presence: true
  validates :accessories, presence: true
  validates :brand, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true


end
```

and I get same error, Any suggest would be great

Comment: Can you show us what your `app/models/tool.rb` looks like, is images one image or multiple images? Are you using 'mini_magick'?

Comment: yes i am using mini_magick, i will get tool.rb and display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you have `has_many_attached :images`

`tool.images` regardless the number of images will alway return an `ActiveSTorage::Attached::Many` which is an `Enumerable` so you will have to loop through it to get each `image`, in the loop each image will be an `ActiveStorage::Blob`, to use `image_tag` you will need a url for the image, to get the url from the blob you would use `url_for(image)`.

Here is an example:

```
<% tool.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag(url_for(image), class: 'some-class') %>
<% end %>
```

In your case you wanted the image to be a link, that is easy to do as well you just have to pass the correct information to `link_to`. You can do this in multiple ways this is the way I think is the easiest to read.

With a link:

```
<% tool.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= link_to "Path to Tool as string" do %>
    <%= image_tag(url_for(image), class: 'some-class') %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for it, yes it more clear and understand what you mean, it working and show images well.  it very learning curving for me as i start Rails 2 weeks ago

Answer (score 1):

This is the API for `link_to`:

```
link_to name, options = {}, html_options = nil
```

This is the API for `image_tag`:

```
image_tag source, options={}
```

Lastly, you're seeing this error:

```
Can't resolve image into URL: undefined `to_model` for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::Many>
```

You are getting this error because you're try to create an image tag with a single image not a collection of "many".

Look at your original working code (superfluous HTML stripped away):

```
 <% @tool.images.each do |image| %>
   <%= link_to image_tag(image, class:"img-thumbnail tools-gallery"), image %>
 <% end %>
```

Notice how you are looping through all the images? That is because a `@tool` has many images. It is an array of images. Inside the `link_to` block, you're defining an `image_tag` properly with a single image as the reference. Now lets look at your erroneous code:

```
<% @tools.each do |tool| %>
  <%= tool.images %>
  <%= image_tag(tool.images, class:"thumbnail"), images %>
<% end %>
```

This is weird. You're calling this:

```
<%= tool.images %>
```

Which just displays an instance of `#<ActiveStorage::Attached::Many>` and you're calling this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(tool.images, class:"thumbnail"), images %>
```

Which just attempts (and fails) to link an array of images to a single image_tag instance which we know is invalid thanks to the api. You likely want to do this:

```
<% @tools.each do |tool| %>
   <%= tool.images.each |image| %>
     <%= image_tag(image, class:"thumbnail"), image %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```